# 'login_redirect' v 'woocommerce_login_redirect'

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-memberships

I am investigating redirect functions in WP functions.php.

My site has woocommerce memberships / subscriptions operating.

If I write a regular WP redirect such as:

```
function login_redirect_user() {
  return get_permalink(20);
}
add_filter('login_redirect', 'login_redirect_user');
```

it will not apply to my woocommerce members. Instead of 'login_redirect' do I need to use 'woocommerce_login_redirect'?  If so, why is this the case? Are woocommerce subscribers not also wordpress members?

Thanks, I am bit confused!

CW

Answer (score 0):

Yes, woocommerce handles login separately and does use a different hook. In Woocommerce, the login is custom and the line that redirects users on login looks like this:

```
wp_redirect( wp_validate_redirect( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_login_redirect', remove_query_arg( 'wc_error', $redirect ), $user ), wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) ) ); // phpcs:ignore
```

This is in class-wc-form-handler.php:1027, and the standard login_redirect doesn't get used here. So you can use that filter if you don't want new logins to land on your my-account page.

Woocommerce customers are certainly WordPress 'Users' still, yes. But the frontend login form Woocommerce provides is totally separate from the standard WP login action, and so uses a different hook.